# Are there any other account system attacks I should be aware about?

Tags: passwords, account-security

Not fully sure if these types of questions are allowed here, but don't see anything against it in the help centre so I'm assuming it is. Please point me to a better place to ask if it's not!

I'm making an account system for my website and trying to do my best to protect accounts from several types of attacks but a bit worried, possibly paranoid, that I'm going to miss some. I've not completed the sign-in page yet, but this is the code that allows users to sign up https://hastebin.com/isuhiwavex.php. Currently, I'm trying to:

- Protect it from bots, brute-forcing and other similar suspicious activity using ReCAPTCHA v3 (allowing scores higher than 0.5)
- Requiring passwords be more than 8 characters and contain both upper and lower case characters
- Encrypting passwords with Argon2id with paramaters that take ~0.5 seconds for my server to process (memory cost 20000, time_cost 17, threads 2)
- Making sure emails are in a valid format for XSS and general validity
- Formatting HTML special chars in the username, also for XSS
- Making sure accounts can't be created with usernames/emails that already exist

When I make the login page, the only extra I plan on adding is that only 3 login attempts can be made per minute per IP. I realise an IP isn't the best way of identifying people, but wasn't sure what else I could get that could be stored in my database easily.

Comment: 1) consider wrapping your `password_hash` attempt in a `try{} catch()` to intercept hashing failure;  2) as far as I'm aware the [`threads` option has no impact on the outcome](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/01b3fc03c30c6cb85038250bb5640be3a09c6a32/ext/sodium/sodium_pwhash.c#L72);  3) since you're using *Argon2id* depending on your hardware the `memory_cost` seems low (20kb?) and `time_cost` seems high - on hardware that isn't too busy you'd want tens to hundreds of megabytes and then tune the `ops_limit` to reach the longest delay possible that is still acceptable to your user/s (min 4)

Comment: The memory_cost is apparently in kikibytes so I believe it’s 20mb I’ve set, not kb. Curious what would cause a hashing failure?

Comment: you're correct about it being kikis - it's hinted at in the comment above [`get_options()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/01b3fc03c30c6cb85038250bb5640be3a09c6a32/ext/sodium/sodium_pwhash.c#L30) adjacent .. the current php codebase seems to throw an error if `threads != 1`

Comment: I don't seem to get an error with two threads

Comment: can you please run `php -v` in your server environment?

Comment: @brynk 8.0.11 . I updated a bit ago because I was missing a PDO feature that was only in the newer versions (I believe it was 7.4 that it needed but I thought I might as well go with the newest one if I'm updating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you've asked for another set of eyes to pass over your logic and its code impl that you linked to in your question. (If you edit your question with more detail then I might update this answer.)

The use of *ReCaptcha* has the potential to leak PII depending on what's included in your signup form. ***TODO**: link to terms*. You might consider the use of *hCaptcha* or review which fields are exposed.

The requirement for upper- and lower-case characters is unnecessary if the user is providing a high-entropy password. In my opinion you'd get more mileage imposing a longer minimum length, however, this may frustrate some users further.

There are a couple of things worth noting in the implementation ...

```
  if (strlen($_POST["username"]) < 4 ||
      strlen($_POST["username"]) > 32 ||
      strlen($_POST["pass"]) < 8 ||
      preg_match("/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*$/",$_POST["pass"]) == 0 ||
      preg_match("/^.{1,128}@.{1,63}\..{2,24}$/",$_POST["email"]) == 0) {
```

and

```
  $_POST["pass"] = password_hash(
    $_POST["pass"]
    , PASSWORD_ARGON2ID
    , ['memory_cost' => 20000
        , 'time_cost' => 17
        , 'threads' => 2 ]
  );
```

Prob here is password length is unbounded, and will wind up at the maximum length that `php.ini` or other config will allow a `POST` to be (depending on what type of `<form>` you've presented your user/s). I propose limiting this maximum to some sensible upper limit (eg. 4096, ie, 4k) to reduce opportunity for resource depletion attacks. (This gets fed into the password hashing routine.)

Also that regex match on the password doesn't seem right to me, but I'm a bit rusty with PHP and regex. It seems that the password must have a lower-case followed by a upper-case char, or it's not valid. (Assuming `(?=` is a positive look ahead, but happy to be corrected.)

*(caveat: I'm not certain exactly if PHP uses the Libsodium impl that I've linked to - I might follow this up at some point when i have more time...)*

I checked the [*Libsodium* function](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/6d566070b48efd2fa099bbe9822914455150aba9/src/libsodium/crypto_pwhash/argon2/pwhash_argon2id.c#L182) that (probably) [underlies `password_hash()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/98184afd92fd48d1f15b1225d376ea86acc35cd7/ext/sodium/libsodium.c#L1711) and it [does indeed limit *Argon2id* to a single lane and thread](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/6d566070b48efd2fa099bbe9822914455150aba9/src/libsodium/crypto_pwhash/argon2/pwhash_argon2id.c#L182). I haven't been able to find much on this *Libsodium* design decision, however, on reflection there's a "risk management" argument for this: an errant process won't leave your system unresponsive. (You can also see it takes bytes as input and converts to kB, which was the source of my earlier confusion in my comment.)

(Btw I was confused about PHP throwing an error for specifying more than one thread: it seems to me that it only does that if you use the `sodium_password_hashX()` functions. My prior experience has been using `sodium_crypto_pwhash()`, which is a more direct route to the *Argon2id* hashing function, and the best option if you need compatibility between *Python*- viz. *Pysodium*- and *PHP*.)

Comment: Thanks so much! I’ll have to look into that ReCAPTCHA issue more, though my form only takes username, email and password so as long as it can’t leak the password there shouldn’t be issues. As for password length, I actually do limit it client-side, don’t know why I didn’t do it server-side, so I’ll definitely do that. The Regex definitely works as I did quite a bit of testing with that, don’t worry. Finally, curious why ‘threads’ is an option if that’s the case but suppose I’ll lower that too.

Comment: Can't seem to find anything about that ReCAPTCHA issue online so not sure what you're talking about there. I've not added the password length limit server-side. I've tested the Regex again and that definitely works. As for the threads thing, just looked at the Wiki again and noticed there's a warning saying 'Only available when PHP uses libargon2, not with libsodium implementation.' suggesting I can switch to libargon2 to get this feature. I'll have to do a bit more research into the differences between libargon2 and libsodium before I consider switching, though

Comment: No problems! yep *Libsodium* is a broader library that offers a specific implementation of *Argon2* as one of it's pw-kdf/ pw-hashing options - haven't used libargon2 before.